# Stylizing Lists?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos, interface-builder

I need to bind a list to Core Data (I figure a table is the most practical way) - the thing is, I don't want it to look like a typical table. I have background images for each item (look like tabs) and I want the user to be able to edit the text, just like they would on a table. Does anyone have any insight on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want table functionality with your own graphics. Just use a table with a custom cell class that draws the background you want.

Comment: Custom cell doesn't have any attributes to customize though? Any info on this?